# want to find out the book_id which is written by a single author only and p_id=1

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, having-clause

I have 3 tables.

This is the Person table:

[image: "This is the person table"]

This is the Car table:

[image]

This is Person_car table hloding join column for many to many:

[image]

Now i want to find out the `c_id` (car id) that is owned by a single person and p_id=1.

That means in this scenario i should get c_id as 100 bcs c_id 200 is owned by p_id  1 and 2

Please help me out to write the sql query.

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? Please tag only one database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at your question I understand that you want to find Cars owned by ONLY one person / and p_id = 1 is just an example/. If this is the case, please try:

```
select
   c.id as car_id,
   c.color as car_color,
   c.model as car_model,
   p.id as person_id,
   p.first_name || ' ' || p.last_naem as person_name,
from
   car c
   join person_car pc on (pc.c_id = c.id)
   join pesron p on (p.id = pc.p_id)
where
   c.id in (select c_id from peson_car group by c_id having count(1) = 1)
```

Thanks.

Comment: join person_car pc on (pc.c_id = c.id)
   join pesron p on (p.id = pc.p_id)  ..How this two join statements will going to work plz explain ..I am not good at plsql.

Comment: @sourav - this join will extract data for car and person pair. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select c_id
from person_car
group by c_id
having count(*) = 2                                      -- owned by 2 persons
   and max(case when p_id = 100 then 1 else 0 end) = 1   -- including p_id 100
```

In MySQL, we can shorten the last condition as:

```
and max(p_id = 100) = 1
```